# Connecting to docker PostgreSQL from PhpStorm gives password authentication failed

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, datagrip

## The problem

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL from PhpStorm, but it returns the following error:

```
[28P01] FATAL: password authentication failed for user "app"
```

## The situation

I have the following `.env` file setup:

```ini
POSTGRES_DB=app
POSTGRES_USER=app
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGRES_VERSION=15
```

And the following in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}-alpine
    container_name: database
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
    ports:
      - '5432'

volumes:
  db-data:
```

When running `docker-compose up -d` that does create a container & volume successfully.

So then I enter the following into my PhpStorm:
[image: PhpStorm database configuration]

But then the error pops up, entering the password again doesn't fix anything.
[image: PhpStorm error popup]

I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

## What I've tried

I've rebuilt the container several times with different user & password combinations (making sure to use `docker-compose down -v` to get rid of the volume), all with the same result.

I've tried changing the password by executing `docker exec -it database psql -U app` and then running `ALTER ROLE app WITH PASSWORD 'password'`, but this did not change anything.

I also saw online that it might have to do something with authentication of the user being setup as ident, but I cannot find a way to change this in the `docker-compose.yml` file.

## The question

How could I set this up so I can connect my PhpStorm to the PostgreSQL database properly?

Comment: You are connecting to the wrong database server.  You have a postgres instance running on localhost, or port forwarding from localhost, and that is the one you are trying to connect to.  You should specify the host by name or IP, not by using 'localhost'.  Doing that might require extra configuration, depending on where phpstorm is running.

Comment: @jjanes Do you mean using '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'?
I've tried that now, but that also doesn't seem to work.
I am trying to connect to my local PostgreSQL instance, from my local PhpStorm application. Does it still need more configuration then?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was running Windows 10 with WSL2 (Ubuntu). I had installed Postgres in the Ubuntu instance as part of setting up an app. I'd removed the app but the Postgres server was still running. When I attempted to connect to the Docker Postgres instance using `localhost:5432` I was instead connecting to the WSL2 Postgres instance.

In my case, since I was no longer using Postgres in WSL2 I removed it and this resolved the issue. You could also stop it or use the host name/IP as mentioned by @jjanes

Comment: I am running this on Ubuntu directly though, and I have no Postgres installation outside of the docker container.
For some reason it seemed that the image would randomly use a port to expose to port 5432 so I've added a manual mapping to port 5433 now, and that seems to work for PhpStorm so far.